# How to check which submit is click

Tags: javascript, ajax

i have form with 2 buttons. It is necessary to send ajax only when you press a button with id = 'liq'.

```js
$(document).on('submit','#order_form',function(){

        var _data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({  
            url: window.location.href,
            dataType: "html",
            type: "POST",  
            data: _data,
            success: function(_form){
                $('body').append(_form);
                $("#liqpay").submit();
            }
        });
        return false;

});
});
```

Comment: Please show the form...

Comment: Check the event target.

Comment: @CBroe — The event target is the form element. That won't help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to identify which button triggered a form submission which in turn triggered a submit event.

The easiest way to deal with this is to use a *click* event on the button itself instead of a submit event.